# How should I start Hybrid Animals?

Tags: hybrid-animals

Hybrid Animals for mobile gives me the option of starting from an online account, or by myself.

Which should I choose? What are the benefits/downsides of each?

Answer (score 1):

This is a tutorial on my knowledge of Hybrid animals, Mobile Edition

When you first load Hybrid Animals on mobile, the first thing you will want to do is make a new save file and a new hybrid. When you load in, you have 2 options.

1. Make an online account (less effort, and a HUGE boost early game)
2. Start off yourself (More effort, but you feel satisfied knowing you had no help building your creations)

Let's say you picked Option 1, for now. This one requires you to have 12-15 gems, to buy Furniture Pack one. These can be earned by grinding mystery boxes or buying gems. After you have the pack, open Online. There are lots of people there that can make or break your journey, so be wise.

But what about Option 2? Oh god, you are in for a RIDE.

- Follow the path up to yandi, and enter the red rent. There is a companion on the right, talk to it and have it follow you.
- This little one can be used as a bodyguard for your level 1-3 self since it is level 10.
- The goal here is to make a large coin hoard, so grab Furniture pack 1.
- Grab 3 sticks, open your crafting menu, and make a crafting table. Grab a few more for a pickaxe.
- Mine stone. Press the crafting table and make a stone pickaxe.
- Mine iron, follow the pathway down to Shindo. (Activate the teleporter there by clicking it.)
- Use the anvil and make 3 metal bars.
- Farm animals until you get Crating enough for a metal pickaxe
- Make a new anvil or pickaxe, we shall assume you made a pickaxe.
- Mine titanium patches, and go and make Titanium bars.
- Make a new pickaxe. You need more sticks by now
- Start farming coins from animals.
- Eventually, you want to craft 3 small coin hoards, and 1 big coin hoard.

CONGRATS! You have made it far enough to have considered beaten Hybrid Animals!